# Elasticsearch Cardinality Aggregation giving wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

The count of PARTY_ID in both the aggregation should be same.
In one case it is  3000 and the other case it is sum of all values (2675 + 244 + 41 + 6 + 2 = 2950 ) which are not equal.
What might be the reason ?

```
GET /test/data/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "ASSET_CLASS": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "ASSET_CLASS_WORST"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "ASSET_CLASS": {
               "cardinality": {
                  "field": "PARTY_ID"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Total count": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "PARTY_ID"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Result :

```
{
   "took": 9,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 51891,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "Total count": {
         "value": 3000
      },
      "ASSET_CLASS": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "NPA",
               "doc_count": 49252,
               "ASSET_CLASS": {
                  "value": 2675
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "RESTRUCTURED",
               "doc_count": 2275,
               "ASSET_CLASS": {
                  "value": 244
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "SMA2",
               "doc_count": 308,
               "ASSET_CLASS": {
                  "value": 41
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "SMA1",
               "doc_count": 42,
               "ASSET_CLASS": {
                  "value": 6
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "SMA0",
               "doc_count": 14,
               "ASSET_CLASS": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the [documentation for cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) reads:

> A single-value metrics aggregation that calculates an **approximate**
>   count of distinct values.

(emphasis mine)

An error of 10 out of 3000 is well below 1%, so it's just to be expected.

The cardinality aggregation uses an [enhanced](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/fr//pubs/archive/40671.pdf) version of [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) calculus which has interesting features like constant memory complexity and O(N) time complexity.

If you need more precise results, try an higher setting for the `precision_threshold` parameter.

```
GET /test/data/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "ASSET_CLASS": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "ASSET_CLASS_WORST"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "ASSET_CLASS": {
               "cardinality": {
                  "field": "PARTY_ID",
                  "precision_threshold": 10000
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Total count": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "PARTY_ID",
            "precision_threshold": 10000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Shadocko. Do you have any performance statistics regarding this

Comment: @James nope, you'd have to run benchmarks for your particular setup.